# Oracle querying date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get data from a table where start_date is less than or equal to a particular date and time value:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE START_DATE <= TO_DATE('2/21/2018 2:40:20 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

The error I am getting is `format code appears twice`

I have tried different formats but still cannot get it right

Comment: you can also use trunc(data) for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

1) The format model for minutes is "mi", not "mm".

2) The format model for AM/PM is "AM", not "tt".

So,

```
TO_DATE('2/21/2018 2:40:20 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')
```

Or, easier,

```
TO_DATE('2/21/2018 14:40:20', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

(i.e., a 24-hour clock)